# Connect host machine's SQL Server 2017 from homestead vagrant

Tags: sql-server, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to connect my local/host machine SQL Server from Laravel vagrant homestead. I've been googling all day trying to connect the host machine's database installing different PHP packages but so far have no lucks. I thought I would remove PHP at this point and try to establish the connection inside homestead using sqlcmd instead.

So, I have installed `sqlcmd` in homestead and tried to execute the following command to connect to the host machine's database.

```
sqlcmd -S 10.0.2.2,1433 -U sa -P 'password' -Q "sp_databases"
```

However, I received the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection because an error was encountered during handshakes before login. Common causes include client attempting to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server, server too busy to accept new connections or a resource limitation (memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection due to prelogin failure.
```

However, If I use `sqlcmd` on my host machine and execute the following command, I am able to access the database.

```
sqlcmd -S LAPTOP-ACQES\MSSQL2017 -U sa -P Asdf1234 -Q "sp_databases"
```

In my Homestead.yaml, I have set up port forwarding from:

```
ports:
    - send: 1433
      to: 1433
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say this doesn't work:

```
sqlcmd -S 10.0.2.2,1433 -U sa -P 'password' -Q "sp_databases"
```

Yet this does:

```
sqlcmd -S LAPTOP-ACQES\MSSQL2017 -U sa -P Asdf1234 -Q "sp_databases"
```

In the former, you are using the IP, but no instance name.

Try:

```
sqlcmd -S 10.0.2.2\MSSQL2017 -U sa -P 'password' -Q "sp_databases"
```

Also:
Ensure [TCP/IP is enabled](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx) in SQL Network Configuration.

Verify SQL Server Browser is running.

Allow remote connections in SQL Server properties.

Lock SQL Network configuration to port 1433 on all adapters, and disable dynamic ports (then restart services).

Comment: In the former, It was executed inside `vagrant ssh`, and the second one was executed on the host machine. I've also ensured TCP/IP is enabled `Protocol for MSSQL2017 TCP/IP` is enabled and `SQL Server (MSSQL2017)` is restarted. It shows the following error:

Comment: `vagrant@homestead:~$ sqlcmd -S 10.0.2.2\MSSQL2017 -U sa -P 'password' -Q 'sp_databases'
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more informati
vagrant@homestead:~$`

Comment: If you open services.msc is the SQL Browser service running?

Comment: I can't find `SQL Browser Service` but `SQL Server Browser` is running

Comment: Interesting, do you have a firewall up on the host? Can you drop momentarily to test?  Can you ping/tracert that IP? Can you telnet to port 1433?

Comment: What version of windows is the host just out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 and just turned off all firewalls at `Windows Defender Firewall`. Pinging `10.0.2.2` in `vagrant ssh` 10/10 transmitted & received. I tried `telnet 10.0.2.2` it gives `telnet:Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. I tried `telnet 10.0.2.2 1433` it gives `Escape character is '^]'. Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: It's Windows 10 home and running 
`Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17224.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1016.244
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.16299.15
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.16299.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.16299`

Comment: The `Escape character is...` message; was that preceded by anything mentioning SQL?  That looks like it connected... if telnet failed on 1433 you'd get a refused message.  Add the port # to my suggestion: `sqlcmd -S 10.0.2.2\MSSQL2017,1433 -U sa -P 'password' -Q "sp_databases"`

Comment: Also open SSMS on the host, login, and right click the server name, goto Properties, and under "Connections" make sure "allow remote connections" is enabled.

Comment: `vagrant@homestead:~$ telnet 10.0.2.2 1433
Trying 10.0.2.2...
Connected to 10.0.2.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

and your suggestion gives the same error as second reply.

Comment: `allow remote connections` is enabled in SSMS.

Comment: My last suggestion would be disable the dynamic port setting in SQL Network Config >> TCP/IP, and ensure its locked on 1433, then restart SQL and Browser...  I'm stumped!  Also check SQL's logs... might be something there.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to lock on 1433? I have a list of IP addresses? IP1 `fe80::7ce6:83b8:802b:1d8c%4`, IP10 `127.0.0.1`, IP11 `2001:0:4137:9e76:1889:22b8:ae67:301a`, IP12 `fe80::1889:22b8:ae67:301a`, IP2 `169.254.29.140`, IP3 `fe80::199c:fcdc:ae64:5dc1%15`, IP4 `169.254.93.193`, IP5 `fe80::2d9a:58b0:71f3:90b6%10`, IP6 `192.168.1.27`, IP8 `169.254.248.117`, IP9`::1`, IPll `TCP Dynamic Ports 49679 TCP Port `?

Comment: Under "ALL" at bottom, remove dynamic value, and set tcp port 1433.  Restart services...

Comment: BINGO! I didn't remove dynamic value but set tcp port 1433 and run `sqlcmd -S 10.0.2.2,1433 -U sa -P 'password' -Q "sp_databases"` and it works now! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: BOOM! Glad to help brother.